# Load data in a ListView

Tags: android, database, android-listview

I have a question, if I want to load a ListView directly from a database, for example on the first screen I'll have a search button that will search the database and display the results in another screen in a ListView. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) or [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a few parts, if you don't already know how to start.

1) First you will need to learn how to set up a custom ListView and a generic adapter

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

2) Then you need to figure out how to source your adapter with data pulled from your database
http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-list-view-using-custom-adapter.html